# Update an entity with Hibernate whose only one field is editable in DB

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity class Product that i was given READ grant on the whole entity and UPDATE grant ONLY on the price field in the database. So whenever i call productDao.update(product), even if I changed only the price field value, i`m getting

```
<2020-09-17 14:33:26.735  WARN 26939 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1031, SQLState: 42000> 
<2020-09-17 14:33:26.735 ERROR 26939 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-01031: insufficient privileges> 
<2020-09-17 14:33:26.736  INFO 26939 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements> 
<2020-09-17 14:33:26.737 ERROR 26939 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement]>
```

Comment: Well, you could try to update that field usingJPQL/HQL or make every other property of your entity a read-only property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [dynamic update](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-dynamicupdate), the generated SQL will only try to update the columns that have been modified

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of calling the default .update() method implement your own updating method in which you just execute a HQL update statement which updates one field based on your object's value?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to annotate other properties of Entity as @Column(updatable = false)